# How to localize iOS foreground push notification using cordova?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins

[iOS foreground notification alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Qs5.png)

As you can see on the image, I wanted to change the string of the following

- **Alert Title**
- **Action buttons (Cancel, Open)**

**Framework**

> Ionic 3

**Plugin**

> pushbots-cordova-plugin

Current code implementation

```js
window["plugins"].PushbotsPlugin.initialize(
    "PROJECT_ID",
    {
        "android": {
            "sender_id": "SENDER_ID",
            "icon": "ic_stat_pushbots_sicon"
        },
        "ios": {
            // How to setup here?
        }
    }
);
```

Can someone help me how to properly setup the iOS payload to update the alert notification on foreground?

Your timely help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: You want to change title, or ? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert

Comment: The notification alert automatically shows when there's a new notification received. I want to change the texts of the Title and Action buttons.